# Bar buttons from storyboard are not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a VC that does a modal segue to another VC when the user adds an image either from the camera or photo library. That works no problem. Once in the second VC (AddNewPhotoVC), if the user hits the submit button, which is bar button item in the toolbar, I need to unwind back to the first VC. I've already wired the submit button to the exit on the second VC and can see the unwind segue show up as expected.

The issue is that when I run the app on my device or simulator, the two bar buttons (submit/cancel) will not show up. I even ran the view debugger to make sure they weren't hidden. If I add the buttons in code in the second VC, and they show up! However, that doesn't work for the unwind segue since it's wired to the button in the storyboard.

You can see in the screenshot that the submit/cancel buttons in the storyboard are not visible when it runs. Ironically, I have two bar button items in the first VC and they show up no problem. I've compared the bar button items between the two VCs and can't find any differences. Can someone please help me figure out why these buttons are not showing up?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the attributes Inspector for bar Item, Try to change the tint to a full color.

Comment: Already tried that. As I mentioned, I used the view debugger to make sure it wasn't actually there and just not visible for some simple reason like that.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean by that. The VC in question has an imageView and it is showing an image as you can see in the screenshot...but that might not be what you're referring to.

Comment: Meant add an image to the bar item, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help. I knew that wouldn't work, but I gave it a try....added an image to the bar button and no go. It's just not showing up no matter what.

Comment: I'm guessing here… Could you change transition from automatic to full screen, on all VC ?

Comment: Don't know what that is at all, but no. From storyboard I can see the toolbar just no buttons. If I uncomment the code for toolbar buttons, they display. The only problem there is the buttons from code are not wired to my unwind segue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228372/discussion-between-claude31-and-sonnyb).

Answer (score 0):

One solution to the missing bar button items is to put them inside a Toolbar.

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: As to why the bar button items appear on your first VC, I'm also curious . Maybe share a sample xcode project?